# Calculate angle of moving average

Tags: pine-script, moving-average, trading

I'm trying to calculate the angle of a moving average (n) between the last 2 candles.

I've been using this formula and it gives me a correct angle between 2 candles of a moving average(2) but if I change the value of the MA to eg.20, it will give me the angle of the 20MA, 20 candles apart.

```
angle(_src) =>
    rad2degree=180/3.14159265359  //pi 
    ang=rad2degree*atan((_src[0] - _src[1])/atr(14)) 
ma=ema(src,input(2))
ma_slope=angle(ma)
```

How can I formulate the code to give me the angle of the 20MA between the last 2 candles?

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
study("ma angles - JD")
src = input(ohlc4, title="source")
th = input(2, minval=1, title="threshold for -no trade zones- in degrees")
color_bars = input(false, title="color bars?")
no_trade = input(false, title="black out bars in no trade zones?")

// definition of "Jurik Moving Average", by Everget
jma(_src, _length, _phase, _power) =>
    phaseRatio = _phase < -100 ? 0.5 : _phase > 100 ? 2.5 : _phase / 100 + 1.5
    beta = 0.45 * (_length - 1) / (0.45 * (_length - 1) + 2)
    alpha = pow(beta, _power)
    jma = 0.0
    e0 = 0.0
    e0 := (1 - alpha) * _src + alpha * nz(e0[1])
e1 = 0.0
e1 := (_src - e0) * (1 - beta) + beta * nz(e1[1])
e2 = 0.0
e2 := (e0 + phaseRatio * e1 - nz(jma[1])) * pow(1 - alpha, 2) + 
   pow(alpha, 2) * nz(e2[1])
jma := e2 + nz(jma[1])
jma

//// //// Determine Angle by KyJ //// //// 
angle(_src) =>
    rad2degree = 180 / 3.14159265359  //pi 
    ang = rad2degree * atan((_src[0] - _src[1]) / atr(14))
    ang

    jma_line = jma(src, 10, 50, 1)
jma_line_fast = jma(src, 10, 50, 2)
ma27 = ema(src, 27)
ma83 = ema(src, 83)
ma278 = ema(src, 278)
jma_slope = angle(jma_line)
jma_fast_slope = angle(jma_line_fast)
ma27_slope = angle(ma27)
ma83_slope = angle(ma83)
ma278_slope = angle(ma278)

hline(0)
rising_1 = rising(ma27, 1)
color_1 = color.new(color.green, 75)
falling_1 = falling(ma27, 1)

plot(jma_slope, title="jma slope", style=plot.style_area, color=jma_slope >= 0 ? 
     rising_1 ? color.green : color_1 : falling_1 ? color.red : color.maroon)
plot(jma_fast_slope, title="jma slope", style=plot.style_line, color=jma_fast_slope >= 
     0 ? color.green : color.red, transp=0)
plot(ma27_slope, title="ma27 slope filter", style=plot.style_area, 
     color=abs(ma27_slope) > th ? na : color.yellow)
plot(ma83_slope, title="ma83 slope filter", style=plot.style_area, 
     color=abs(ma83_slope) > th ? na : color.yellow)
plot(ma278_slope, title="ma278 slope filter", style=plot.style_area, 
     color=abs(ma278_slope) > th ? na : color.yellow)
plot(ma27_slope, title="ma27 slope", style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2, 
     color=ma27_slope >= 0 ? color.lime : color.fuchsia)

color_2 = color.new(color.green, 0)
color_3 = color.new(color.red, 0)

plot(ma83_slope, title="ma83 slope", style=plot.style_line, color=ma83_slope >= 0 ? 
     color_2 : color_3)
plot(ma278_slope, title="ma278 slope", style=plot.style_line, color=ma278_slope >= 0 ? 
     color.green : color.red)

plotshape(ma27_slope >= 0 ? ma27 : na, style=shape.triangleup, 
          location=location.bottom, color=color.green)
plotshape(ma27_slope < 0 ? ma27 : na, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.top, 
          color=color.red)
plotshape(ma27_slope >= 0 and not(ma27_slope[1] >= 0) ? ma27 : na, 
          style=shape.triangleup, location=location.bottom, size=size.tiny, 
          color=color.green)
plotshape(ma27_slope < 0 and not(ma27_slope[1] < 0) ? ma27 : na, 
          style=shape.triangledown, location=location.top, size=size.tiny, 
          color=color.red)

rising_2 = rising(ma27, 1)
falling_2 = falling(ma27, 1)

barcolor(color_bars ? no_trade and abs(ma27_slope) <= th ? color.white : jma_slope >= 
         0 ? rising_2 ? color.lime : color.green : falling_2 ? color.fuchsia : 
         color.red : na)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes